# How to solve this triple intergral $I=\iiint_{Q}\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dv$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, multiple-integral

$$
I \equiv \iiint_{Q}\frac{{\rm d}v}{x^2+y^2}
$$ Which $Q$ is a solid bounded above by $z=4-x^2-y^2$ and below by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$.

---

I have tried with this multiple integration by using cylindrical coordinate.
As a result, I got

$$
I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int
\int_{\sqrt{9-r^{2}}}^{4-r^{2}}\,\,\frac{1}{r}
\,{\rm d}z\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\theta
$$

I cannot determine the value of $r$ and I cannot solve this integral. Please give me some hints or other way to solve this triple integral. Thank in advanced.

---

I have written with wrong sign. It was $z=4-x^2+y^2$ Here is right problem. Actually, $Q$ is a solid bounded above by $z=4-x^2+y^2$ and bounded below the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=9$.

The red dot that I noted in this graph. It is a region that I intended.
[image: Region picture]

Comment: You could also try with spherical coordinates if cilindrical doesn't work out.

Comment: The integral doesn't converge

Comment: Is $Q$ *all* the points below the surface and outside the sphere, or are there other constraints e.g. $z\ge0$ or $r\le4$?

Comment: @J.G. https://www.math3d.org/ZwTf1nHV For my intended, I think it bounded between sphere and surface.

Comment: @J.G. $Q$ is all the points above the surface and inside the sphere.

Comment: @J.G. I have added the region in form of picture that I noted it with red color.

Comment: I thought writing $Q:=S\setminus T$ in terms of the disjoint sets$$S:=\{(x,\,y,\,z)|0\le z\le4-x^2+y^2\},\,T:=\{(x,\,y,\,z)|z\ge0,\,x^2+y^2+z^2\le9\}$$would help, but $s:=\int_S\frac{dV}{x^2+y^2},\,t=\int_T\frac{dV}{x^2+y^2}$ both diverge. There may be a helpful regularization.

Comment: @J.G. Could you explain me about my region of this integral?